# Smarty проблема с загрузкой шаблона

Tags: php, smarty

Здраствуйте! У меня вот проблемка нарисовалась, может подскажите как решить просто не сталкивался раньше.
Я создал функцию загрузки шаблона и загрузки страницы.

```
function loadPage($smarty, $controllerName, $actionName = "index"){
    include_once PathPrefix . $controllerName . PathPostfix;

    $function = $actionName . "Action";
    $function($smarty);
}

/*
 * Загрузка шаблона
 * 
 * $smarty - обьект шаблонизатора
 * $templateName - название файла шаблона
 * 
 * методом display() передаем название шаблона как параметр
 */

function loadTemplate($smarty, $templateName){
    $smarty->display($templateName.TemplatePostfix);
}
```

Создал шаблон index.tpl

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{$pageTitle}</title>
    </head>
    <body>  
        {$pageTitle}    
    </body>
</html>
```

Когда в строке набираю http://myshop.local/?controller=index&action=index у меня выскакивает ошибка следущая :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'SmartyException' with message 'Unable to load template file 'index.tpl'' in C:\xampp\htdocs\myshop.local\library\Smarty\libs\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatebase.php:127 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\myshop.local\library\Smarty\libs\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatebase.php(362): Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase->fetch('index.tpl', NULL, NULL, NULL, true) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\myshop.local\library\mainFunctions.php(29): Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase->display('index.tpl') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\myshop.local\controllers\IndexController.php(18): loadTemplate(Object(Smarty), 'index') #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\myshop.local\library\mainFunctions.php(16): indexAction(Object(Smarty)) #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\myshop.local\www\index.php(13): loadPage(Object(Smarty), 'Index', 'index') #5 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\myshop.local\library\Smarty\libs\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatebase.php on line 127
```

Я только только начал расбиратся со всем этим и не могу понять где я протупил ,  прозьба подсказать. Спасибо!

Comment: Вы правильный путь до файла указали? Смарти не находит файл.

Comment: function loadTemplate($smarty, $templateName){
    $smarty->display('view/default/index.tpl');
}


вот даже если так напримую прописал все равно не хочет работать. странно.

Comment: @Vitaliisss ошибка явно указывает на то, что у вас неверно указан путь. Одна однозначна. Также проверьте права на файл.

Comment: @lampa я совсем новичок в этих делах, подскажи плз как проверить права на файл и если надо как их поменять? спасибо!

Comment: @Vitaliisss у вас windows/linux?

Comment: @lampa у меня windows

Comment: @Vitaliisss эм, тогда проверяйте путь. Права на linux только выставляются по хорошему.

Comment: я проверил, что возращается в пути  -- index.tpl
это и есть мой шаблон. в файле конфигурации я прописовал две константы по поводу путей к шаблону 
//путь к файлам  шаблонов(*.tpl)

//>используемый шаблон
$template = "default";
define("TemplatePrefix", "../view/{$template}/");
define("TemplatePostfix", ".tpl"); // рассширения шаблонов смарти

по сути оно должно работать,  но уже убил столько времени что уже даже не знаю что должно , а что нет(

Comment: У меня вот такое:
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536327/smarty-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-unable-to-load-template-file

Answer (score 2):

Привет! Столкнулся с такой же проблемой. 
И сразу вопрос: почему не дебажил ?) Автор же настоятельно рекомендовал это сделать =)
Когда бы ты вывел переменную smarty на экран, ты бы увидел бы вот такую строчку:

```
 [joined_template_dir] =>
../views/$template\
```

и сразу все понял бы где у тебя ошибка=)
Надо просто подредактировать эту строчку в файле config.php - заменить

```
define('TemplatePrefix','../views/$template/');
```

на

```
define('TemplatePrefix','../views/'.$template.'/');
```

Удачи!